# node-gyp rebuild command freezes

Tags: node-gyp

When I run the rebuild code it doesn't end with ok, it just gets stuck, what could cause such a problem?

```
^CPS C:\Users\Demir> node-gyp rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@2.0.1
gyp info using node@0.12.4 | win32 | x64
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/node-v0.12.4.tar.gz
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/node-v0.12.4.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was because of network timeout when download the source code of node.

I resolve this by:

- download node-v0.12.4.tar.gz from mirror server manually
- rm -rf ~/.node-gyp
- mkdir ~/.node-gyp
- tar zxf node-v0.12.4.tar.gz -C ~/.node-gyp
- mv ~/.node-gyp/node-v0.12.4 ~/.node-gyp/0.12.4
- printf "9\n" > ~/.node-gyp/0.12.4/installVersion

(last step is told node-gyp that download have finished, otherwise it will be download again)